# How can I obtain a list of modified files within a 'changeset' range from team foundation server through a windows form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, tfs

I'm trying to create a tool which will help my team perform code reviews on a more regular basis without it's usual massive overhead.

At the moment the manual process involves using Team Foundation Sidekicks to identify the Changesets and then exporting that to excel to filter the results to find which items need to be reviewed (e.g. code files).

I've heard mention of using a TFS API, but found very little help online possibly because I was asking google 'the wrong questions'.

Answer (score 0):

Colin, why are your developers checking code in before it is reviewed? Why not have the developers shelve their changes and then review the shelveset?

IAC, there is a TFS API. It can be accessed by including the following files:

TeamFoundation.Client

TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client

The API is pretty straightforward. In fact, I am using it as we speak to programmatically check files in and out in a C# application.